# Override component styles via Box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

MUI's [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/box/#box) say that it's possible for a Box wrapper to override its child's styling with the `clone` option, like this:

```
<Box color="red" clone>
   <Button>Click me</Button>
</Box>
```

As far as I understand, it's supposed to `cloneElement` its child and inject the styles. However, it doesn't seem to work at all - not with buttons, nor typographies, nor any other component.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm yes clone has some issues seems it will be removed in v5

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18496#issuecomment-557835104

for the moment could use like but not good :(

```html
<Box color="red">
   <Button color='inherit'>Click me</Button>
</Box>
```